# Ajax call isn't working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I tried to pass a value to method of controller ( am using codeigniter ) using ajax through jquery. I called the ajax method with in a click event, the click event is working fine, but the ajax is not call. Plz help me. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#sql_format').click(function(){alert('hi');
    $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url('adhoc/sql_formater'); ?>',
            data : '',
            type: 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
    });
});
```

when click the "#sql_format" it displays alert box with 'hi' message. But it doesn't call ajax. Here the adhoc is controller and sql_formater is method.

Controller code

```
function sql_formater(){
            $sql = $this->input->post('query');

            return $sql;
        }
```

Comment: Did you check your Network Tab?

Comment: Please provide the controller action code in order for us to understand the problem better.

Comment: Network Tab means, plz explain to me

Comment: One more thing, `url : '<?php echo site_url('adhoc/sql_formater'); ?>',` single or double quote should write properly for parsing case, such `url : '<?php echo site_url("adhoc/sql_formater"); ?>',`

Comment: i tried it with single and double quotes but it doesn't working

Comment: **Please provide the controller action code in order for us to understand the problem better**

Comment: You have not passed any query variable in your ajax call

Comment: You are sending Blank data to the controller in data:"",

Comment: $('#sql_format').click(function(){
     $.ajax({
       url : '<?php echo site_url("adhoc/sql_formater"); ?>',
       data : {query: 'select * from query'}',
       type: 'post',
       dataType : 'json',
       success : function(data){
        alert(data);
       }
     });
    });

Comment: i tried this one also

Comment: Write your url as:- "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"adhoc/sql_formater";

Comment: @RaviHirani it is not working

Comment: What element of `$('#sql_format')`? can you provide html for that?

Comment: Ajax expect json data to be return, so try this echo json_encode($sql);

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali $('#sql_format') is a button, i planed like to trigger ajax when clicking that button,

Comment: @MasoodRehman the flow is not redirect to controller method

Comment: button? is it type `submit` or type `button`?

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali it is a button type

Comment: oh i see, and did you ever try to look at network tab to check either the ajax end point really reach or not

Answer (score 0):

Try to set all parameters to ajax post like in example, see my answer here

> [Uploaded File name send through Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35298710/uploaded-file-name-send-through-ajax/35308747#35308747)

```
  var postData = new FormData();

  $.ajax({
  processData: false, /* important */
  contentType: false, /* important */
  type: "POST",
  url: 'b.php',
  data: postData, /* **  postData */
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ alert(textStatus); }, /* show error */
  success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert(data);  },  /* show result*/
  dataType: 'html'  /* I change it ot html for this example*/
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller code

```
function sql_formater()
    {
       $sql = $this->input->post('query');
       header('Content-type: application/json');                
       echo json_encode(array("response"=>$sql));
       exit;
    }
```

And in view

```
$('#sql_format').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url : '<?php echo site_url("adhoc/sql_formater"); ?>',
            data : {'query':'select * from table'},
            type: 'post',
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data){
                alert(data.response);
            }
    });
});
```